# Display button using firebase reference. button is shown apparently without verification

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Display button using firebase reference. button is shown apparently without verification.

the button should check if there is a casino node if it does not display it displays buyCassino if it exists openCassino will be displayed, but it is being shown apparently without verification, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
   final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final String userId = user.getUid();


    ref.child("users").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                if (ref.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("cassino") != null); {
                    buyCassino.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } if  (ref.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("cassino") == null ); {
                    openCassino.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }



            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {



        }
    });
```

my xml file

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/buyCassino"
                android:layout_width="183dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Buy Cassino - $250"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/openCassino"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="ABRIR CASSINO"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after the if condition

```
            if (ref.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("cassino") != null) {
                buyCassino.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } if  (ref.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("cassino") == null ) {
                openCassino.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
```

Comment: I have a single problem it does not check the first if. only makes the button visible. do you know what could be wrong?